# what is an optimized way of writing this exception handling?

Tags: python

I do this error handling a lot, is there a shorter way of writing this try except block ?

```
        try:
            config = item['asset'][0]['config']
        except:
            config = 'None'
```

like a pythonic oneliner maybe ?

Comment: What is your error that gets thrown? You might be able to just check for the error like a one line if statement so that you don't try to access that element of `item` on the event that it won't work. Something like `config = item['asset'][0]['config'] if <The condition that doesn't throw the error> else config = 'None'`

Comment: Iam looking at a large data source and I have such indexing and dict lookup all over and many times i dont find values and Iam allowed to fill 'None' for those so Iam looking for a oneliner

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write a method for it so you can call it whenever you need?

```
def validate_item(item):
    try:
        config_letter = item['asset'][0]['config']
    except:
        config_letter = 'None'
```

Obviously this is just a rough outline so you can reformat the params however you need.

Comment: Probably return config_letter in case it's not a global variable; that way the call could look like: `config_letter = validate_item(item)`

Comment: I cant afford to do that, thats much many more lines. There must be a oneliner for the above

Comment: If the way you're doing it now is writing a try/except block every time you need to verify it, how is this more lines?